# How to extract information out of an api in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am currently trying to extract information out of the Openweather API for my python project. I just wish for the weather and location to be extracted from the xml file put I am unaware of how to get just this information. I have used if statements inside of a for loop to remove characters in the text which I don't want to be saved, but how can I do this for all of the information which is being displayed? is there a way to just extract the lines which I want out of the api? the code I am using is :

```
import requests

 print "enter a city"
 city = raw_input()
 print "enter a country"
 country = raw_input()

 fh = open('/home/Ricky92d4/weather.txt', 'w')

info = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city +','+ country +'&mode=xml')
fh.write(info.text)
fh.close()

fl = open('/home/Ricky92d4/weather.txt')
new_city = fl.read()

fl.close()

for line in new_city:
   if line.startswith ('<'):
       new_city = new_city.replace('<', '')

   if line.endswith ('>'):
       new_city = new_city.replace('>', '')

   if (line.startswith('?')):
       new_city = new_city.replace('?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?', '')

   if (line.endswith('/')):
       new_city = new_city.replace('/', '\n')

 print new_city
```

Comment: The proper solution is to use an XML parser. The initial learning curve will set you back a few hours but you should be able to quickly regain that by having acquired the skill to use a simple, robust, general-purpose tool which you will need again many times in the future.

Comment: Saving the information to a file seems superfluous and will create an I/O bottleneck. Just keep the XML structure in memory ... once you have figured out how to parse it.

Comment: Because it can't be restated enough: do not try to parse xml with regex. Just a heads up. Take a look at [Elementree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Comment: (There's no regex here; but manually picking apart the XML with static string replacements is hardly any better.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> city='Boston'
>>> country='USA'
>>> info = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city +','+ country +'&mode=xml')
>>> doc = etree.fromstring(info.text)
>>> doc.find('city').find('coord').get('lon')
'-71.06'
>>> doc.xpath('/current/city/coord/@lon')[0]
'-71.06'
```

But it appears that there is also a JSON API, which would probably make your life much easier:

```
>>> info = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city +','+ country +'&mode=json')
>>> info.json()['coord']['lon']
-71.06
```

This is much easier because the JSON response can be parsed directly into Python data structures.